# jquery radiobutton doesn't fire event at first click

Tags: jquery, events, click

https://jsfiddle.net/8g94ykta/

Radiobutton fire event only at second/third click and only show only first result. How to fix it? Thank you.

```
<input type="radio" name="group" checked="checked" value="first">A
<input type="radio" name="group" value="second">B
<input type="radio" name="group" value="third">C
<p>
<span id="result">-</span>
</p>



 $('input[type="radio"][name=group]:checked').click(function(){
      if (this.value=='first') {
            $("#result").text("first value");}
      else if (this.value=='second') {
                $("#result").text("second value");}
       else if (this.value=='third') {
                $("#result").text("third value");}

  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this: `$('input[type="radio"][name=group]')` instead `$('input[type="radio"][name=group]:checked')`

You need to trigger the `click` event for all `radio` elements

```
$('input[type="radio"][name=group]').click(function(){
   if (this.value=='first') {
      $("#result").text("first value");}
   else if (this.value=='second') {
      $("#result").text("second value");}
   else if (this.value=='third') {
      $("#result").text("third value");}                
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector only attaches a `click` handler to the element that is currently checked, so it will only fire if you click on that element alone.  You need to attach it to all the elements instead:

```
$('input[type="radio"][name=group]').click(function() {
```